# How to fix "invalid property value" from combobox after changing combobox format

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, userform

After changing combobox5 format, now it give "invalid property value.

```
    `Option Explicit
Private Sub ComboBox5_Change()
ComboBox5 = Format(ComboBox5, "00%")
End Sub
' CODE MIMIC "DATA VALIDATION"
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Me.ComboBox1.List = Worksheets("B16.5 & B16.47 SERIES A").Range("R15:R16").Value
    Me.ComboBox2.List = Worksheets("B16.5 & B16.47 SERIES A").Range("U5:U9").Value
    Me.ComboBox3.List = Worksheets("B16.5 & B16.47 SERIES A").Range("B5:B40").Value
    Me.ComboBox4.List = Worksheets("B16.5 & B16.47 SERIES A").Range("R5:R12").Value
    Me.ComboBox5.List = Worksheets("B16.5 & B16.47 SERIES A").Range("T5:T10").Value
    Me.ComboBox6.List = Worksheets("B16.5 & B16.47 SERIES A").Range("R18:R19").Value


End Sub
`
```

Comment: hi. shouldnt be ComboBox5.format ("00%") or something like that ?

Comment: I just tried that ' conbobx5.format ("00%")     didn't work

Answer (score 1):

ComboBox values can only be what's in their list.  Note that getting the `.Value` property of cells gets their underlying value (like .57) instead of their formatted display value (like 57%), which is likely why you're having this issue.  Unfortunately, you'd need to load the values into an array, and then format those values to the desired display text, and then load them into the combobox list.  There's not really a one-liner solution for this that I can think of, but something like this should work (and then no need for a change event):

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("B16.5 & B16.47 SERIES A")

    Dim aLists(1 To 6, 1 To 2) As Variant
    'This is the combobox               'This is the range where the combobox gets its values
    Set aLists(1, 1) = Me.ComboBox1:    Set aLists(1, 2) = ws.Range("R15:R16")
    Set aLists(2, 1) = Me.ComboBox2:    Set aLists(2, 2) = ws.Range("U5:U9")
    Set aLists(3, 1) = Me.ComboBox3:    Set aLists(3, 2) = ws.Range("B5:B40")
    Set aLists(4, 1) = Me.ComboBox4:    Set aLists(4, 2) = ws.Range("R5:R12")
    Set aLists(5, 1) = Me.ComboBox5:    Set aLists(5, 2) = ws.Range("T5:T10")
    Set aLists(6, 1) = Me.ComboBox6:    Set aLists(6, 2) = ws.Range("R18:R19")

    'Loop through your list of comboboxes and load values
    Dim aTemp As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    For i = LBound(aLists, 1) To UBound(aLists, 1)
        Select Case aLists(i, 1).Name
            'Specify the comboboxes that should have the percent format here
            Case "ComboBox5"
                aTemp = aLists(i, 2).Value
                For j = LBound(aTemp, 1) To UBound(aTemp, 1)
                    aTemp(j, 1) = Format(aTemp(j, 1), "00%")
                Next j
                aLists(i, 1).List = aTemp

            'Can use this same method to apply different formats as well to different comboboxes, add additional conditions here

            'Otherwise just load the values as is
            Case Else
                aLists(i, 1).List = aLists(i, 2).Value

        End Select
    Next i

End Sub
```

Screenshot of result:

[image]

Comment: @ tigeravatar: with that code, i keep getting error " next without for", i block next i and get a "for without next". back and forth.

Comment: @Byron I tested the code and can verify it functions properly as provided.  Did you modify it?

Comment: @ tigeravatar no ill recopy it again

Comment: hmm... your version of excel may require an End Select statement, just a sec, i'll add it

Comment: FWIW this has nothing to do with the version of Excel, it's VBA language syntax, unchanged since launch in 1993...

Comment: @ tigeravatar  same issue. ... im on excel 2016

Comment: @Byron I have validated the code runs as expected for me and have included a screenshot of the result.  If you are still getting an error, please edit your question to show your full userform code (including what you've copied from this answer) so that further debugging can be performed.  You may need to step through your code with F8 to find the cause.